# unserialize(): Error at offset 0 after attempting to download and install plugin within control panel

Tags: plugins

Steps to reproduce:

1. Log into control panel,
2. Go to Plugin Store tab and install a plugin (in my case hillholliday/craft-user-manual or dolphiq/sitemap),
3. Plugin installation error screen,
4. Navigate to /admin and entire site errors out with this message (control panel and frontend)

`unserialize(): Error at offset 0 in ProjectConfig.php`

[image]

Unsuccessful attempts to correct the issue include:

1. Restoring latest database backup
2. Restoring backed up composer.json and composer.lock files from storage/composer-backups and running `composer install`
3. Clearing `storage/runtime/cache`

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue, and insights to why it's happening in the first place?

Comment: Have you already tried to install the plugins via composer? I have reproduced the steps and I don't get the error.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yes, I tried uninstalling and re-installing the plugins via composer and that didn't work either. I eventually got my site back up and running after scrambling and trying a bunch of different things. I think what ended up working was restoring backed up composer.json and composer.lock files, deleting everything in /vendor directory, and then running composer install.

Answer (score 2):

I think what ended up working was restoring backed up composer.json and composer.lock files, deleting everything in /vendor directory, and then running `composer install`

Comment: I ran into this issue while taking over a project. My issue was my DB had updated plugins that my `composer.json` file didn't have. Removing the `vendor` folder and the `composer.` files, then adding the correct `composer.json` file that matched the updated DB worked as well.